# How to enlage a border between two rows of a table in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a message box in HTML with the following code:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.table_header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table_header">Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Example message</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The border (line) between the Title and the Example message should contact the border of the table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding and border-spacing on the table, and add padding to the cells:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table_header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-width: 1px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table_header">Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Example message</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```